# Create new entry (One to One Polymorphic relationship)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

### Premise

I am creating a small app with User profiles that can host a list of items of different types.

Each `Item` can be a `Link`, `Card`, `Video`. So each layout can be optimized accordingly. A bit like Tumblr, if you like.

### The setup

For this reason, I've opted to use a one-to-one a polymorphic relationship (maybe overkill?), with an `items` table that has additional columns like `position` (so that a user can reorder the items).

The **`items`** table:

```
id
user_id (foreign key)
itemable_id
itemable_type
position
...
```

My models look like:

**`Item`** model

```php
public function itemable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

public function user()
    ...
```

**`Link`** model

```php
public function item()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('\App\Item', 'itemable');
    }

public function user()
    ...
```

**`Card`** model

```php
public function item()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('\App\Item', 'itemable');
    }

public function user()
    ...
```

…and so on for the other `Item` types.

Finally, in `ItemController`, I'm creating a dummy Link for debug purposes:

```php
    // ...

    $newLink = new Link();
    $newLink->url = 'example.org';
    $newLink->title = 'Example Website NEW';
    $newLink->user_id = $user->id;

    $user->items()->save($newLink);

    // ...
```

But, unlike how I expected, the new entry in the `items` table doesn't get created. I have to that myself instead, manually once I've stored the `$newLink` Link.

### The question

Is this normal? I would have expected to have `Link` (with `itemable_id` and `itemable_type` created automatically.

If so, I'm definitely missing something here. How can I make Laravel create the `items` entry automatically?

Answer (score 0):

use `associate` so it will be like below:

```
$user->items()->associate($newLink);
```

Comment: Not working. :\ It gives me a :
`BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::associate()` error

I've tried `attach`, too, but I get the same type of error.